# stretch the height of content to the entire page

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to stretch the height of the content on the rest of the page and leave padding 10 pixels below. The page should not have scrolling. vh and calc is well supported by browsers, but I can’t understand how to calc remaining content height correctly

```css
html, body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: calc(100vh - 82px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="search" placeholder="search">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the body has a default margin that you need to remove

Comment: in the examples that you sent there is a scroll page. I need an example page without scrolling. I updated my code, maybe it is correct